# $ \Bbb B( \Bbb R^{n+m} ) = \Bbb B( \Bbb R^{n} ) \times \Bbb B( \Bbb R^{m} ) $

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $ \Bbb B( \Bbb R^{n} ) $ denote a Borel algebra on $ \Bbb R^n $.

Why is it true, that:

$ \Bbb B( \Bbb R^{n+m} ) = \Bbb B( \Bbb R^{n} ) \times \Bbb B( \Bbb R^{m} ) $

I think, that "$ \supset$" is easier, because if we have $ A = N \times M \in \Bbb B( \Bbb R^{n} ) \times \Bbb B( \Bbb R^{m} ) $ there are some families of sets $ \{ N_k \}$ and $ \{ M_k \} $ in respectively $ \Bbb R^n $ and $ \Bbb R^m$, which generate $N$ and $M$. But families $ \{ N_k \times \Bbb R^m\}$,  $ \{ N_k \times  \emptyset\}$, $ \{ \Bbb R^n \times M_k\}$ and $ \{ \emptyset \times M_k\}$ are contained in $\Bbb R^{n+m}$ so they generate $A$.

Is my proof correct?

How to prove "$ \subset$"? Is it analogous to " $\supset$", but starting from the end of the proof?

Comment: It cant be true.

Comment: The whole statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\subset$, let $W$ be an open subset on $\Bbb R^{n+m}$, it can write as $W=\cup_iU_i\times V_i$ where $U_i$ resp. $V_i$ is an open on $\Bbb R^n$ resp. $\Bbb R^m$, it follow that $\mathcal{O}(\Bbb R^{n+m})\subset \mathcal{O}(\Bbb R^n)\times \mathcal{O}(\Bbb R^m)\subset \Bbb B(\Bbb R^n)\times \Bbb B(\Bbb R^m)$, so $\Bbb B(\Bbb R^{n+m})\subset \Bbb B( \Bbb R^n)\times \Bbb B(\Bbb R^m)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that to show $\sigma(A)\subset \sigma(B)$ for $A$, $B$ collections of subsets of a space, it suffices to show that $A\subset \sigma(B)$. With this in mind, it is enough to check that open subsets of $\mathbb R^{m+n}$ lie in $\mathbb B(\mathbb R^n) \times \mathbb B(\mathbb R^m)$. For this, use that a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable unions.

This argument generalizes to show that $\mathbb B(X\times  Y) = \mathbb B(X)\times \mathbb B (Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are [second countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space) topological spaces.